# about Java.sql.TimeStamp and angular

Tags: angular, spring-boot, timestamp, ngb-datepicker

i am working on a website (angular 9, spring boot). 
i need a user to be able to send me a Date AND Time of a certain event,
while on the java side i am working with `java.sql.TimeStamp`
and in angular i am using both `NgbDatepicker` (for date) and `Time` (for hours&minutes). what i want to do is to combine them to be the same as the `java.sql.TimeStamp` with the TimeZone. 

 
is there any idea that should help me, or should i maybe send them as they are to the java and create a new TimeStamp each time before putting into the DB?

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `java.sql.TimeStamp`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `OffsetDateTime` or `LocalDateTime`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). Since JDBC 4.2 you can directly save these types to your SQL database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same promblem: My solution: I got a 'date' (as ISO 8601 string) from backend. In the frontend I created a second variable (a copy): One copy for date picker and one for time input. Before sending back to backend I joined these two values into one iso string.

```
const date = new Date(datevalue); // datevalue from datepicker
const hhmm = timevalue.split(':');
date.setHours(parseInt(hhmm[0], 10));
date.setMinutes(parseInt(hhmm[1], 10));
date.setSeconds(0);
date.setMilliseconds(0);
this.resultingDate = date;
```

In my solution :

date: input matDatepicker

time: input type="time"